# Wrapping an xml document loses utf coding

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server I'm using

```
select * from [Database].[dbo].[Table] for xml path ('whatever')
```

which gives me an xml output with, importantly, newline `&#x0D;` notifiers on any entries that have the new lines.

I need this output wrapped in a few more xml formatting elements but using

```
select '<?xml version="1.0"?><root><whateverses>'
 + (select * from [Database].[dbo].[Table] for xml path ('whatever'))
 + '</whateverses></root>';
```

returns just a string, with the newlne notifiers MISSING.

How can I preserve these? How do I wrap my xml in a few extras while keeping the output as an xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trying to wrap the XML in varchar/string you're implicitly converting the XML to varchar/string. If you want to embed the XML in other tags try something like the following:

```sql
select *
into [dbo].[Foo]
from (values ('Hello', 'World') ) Src ([Bar], [Baz]);

select *
from [dbo].[Foo]
for xml path ('whatever');

select (
  select *
  from [dbo].[Foo]
  for xml path ('whatever'), type
)
for xml path('whateverses'), root('root');
```

Which yields the XML results:

```xml
<whatever>
  <Bar>Hello</Bar>
  <Baz>World</Baz>
</whatever>
```

and:

```xml
<root>
  <whateverses>
    <whatever>
      <Bar>Hello</Bar>
      <Baz>World</Baz>
    </whatever>
  </whateverses>
</root>
```

Comment: Awesome, it was that very last line to add the MULTIPLE elements that did it. `for xml path('whateverses'), root('root');`